# Why don't jquery datatable get filled with newly updated data after searching?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am filling my jQuery Datatable (ver: 1.10.15) from WebAPI and it works but when I search in datatable via searchbox then it doesn't fill the datatable with updated data. Why?

I checked, it sends search value and brings the updated data from server but doesn't populate the table with newly returned data.

```js
function show()
{                               
  $('#example').DataTable({
//  "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "retrieve": true,
    "destroy": true,
    "pagination": true,
//  "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    "ajax": "http://localhost:28071/Users"
  });
}
```

**UPDATE:**

C# api code:

```
namespace WebApiHimHer.Controllers
{
    public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public DTResult GetData([FromUri]DTParameters v)
        {

            List<string[]> s = new List<string[]>();

            //List<basicoperations> s = new List<basicoperations>();

            basicoperations bo= new basicoperations();


            s = bo.getUsers(v.length, v.start, 1, v.sortOrder, v.search.Value);

            DTResult r = new DTResult();
            r.draw = 1;
            r.recordsFiltered = s.Count;
            r.recordsTotal = 100; ;
            r.data = s;

            return r;
        }
    }

    public class DTResult
    {
        public int draw { get; set; }
        public int recordsTotal { get; set; }
        public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }
        public List<string[]> data { get; set; }
    }
    public abstract class DTRow
    {
        public virtual string DT_RowId
        {
            get { return null; }
        }
        public virtual string DT_RowClass
        {
            get { return null; }
        }
        public virtual object DT_RowData
        {
            get { return null; }
        }
    }
    public class DTParameters
    {
        public int draw { get; set; }
        public DTColumn[] columns { get; set; }
        public DTOrder[] order { get; set; }
        public int start { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }
        public DTSearch search { get; set; }
        public string sortOrder
        {
            get
            {
                return columns != null && order != null && order.Length > 0
                    ? (columns[order[0].Column].Data + (order[0].Dir == DTOrderDir.DESC ? " " + order[0].Dir : string.Empty))
                    : null;
            }
        }
    }
    public class DTColumn
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Searchable { get; set; }
        public bool Orderable { get; set; }
        public DTSearch Search { get; set; }
    }
    public class DTOrder
    {
        public int Column { get; set; }
        public DTOrderDir Dir { get; set; }
    }
    public enum DTOrderDir
    {
        ASC,
        DESC
    }
    public class DTSearch
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public bool Regex { get; set; }


    }

}
```

I am posting a Request and response after initial table load and after performing a search

After initial load:

- Request:

**_
1503560388132
columns[0][data]
0
columns[0][name]
columns[0][orderable]
true
columns[0][search][regex]
false
columns[0][search][value]
columns[0][searchable]
true
columns[1][data]
1
columns[1][name]
columns[1][orderable]
true
columns[1][search][regex]
false
columns[1][search][value]
columns[1][searchable]
true
draw
2
length
10
order[0][column]
0
order[0][dir]
asc
search[regex]
false
search[value]
2
start
0**

Response:

**{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":4,"recordsFiltered":25,"data":[["Hunain","123"],["hk","asd"],["daenerys Targaryen"
,"123"],["",""]]}**

After performing a search:

- Request:

**_
1503560409319
columns[0][data]
0
columns[0][name]
columns[0][orderable]
true
columns[0][search][regex]
false
columns[0][search][value]
columns[0][searchable]
true
columns[1][data]
1
columns[1][name]
columns[1][orderable]
true
columns[1][search][regex]
false
columns[1][search][value]
columns[1][searchable]
true
draw
2
length
10
order[0][column]
0
order[0][dir]
asc
search[regex]
false
search[value]
w
start
0**

- Response:

**{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":1,"recordsFiltered":25,"data":[["Waleed","123"]]}**

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing your serverside script.  Somehow data is sent in a improper way.

Comment: @davidkonrad: sure, I am updating the question

Comment: @davidkonrad updated the question with server code, ajax request and response

Answer (score 1):

The reason was that `draw` parameter being sent and received was not same because I took `draw` static in the server code so mismatched. I returned the same `draw` parameter as it was sent.

---

From the [**docs**](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) :

> The draw counter that this object is a response to - from the draw
>   parameter sent as part of the data request. Note that it is strongly
>   recommended for security reasons that you cast this parameter to an
>   integer, rather than simply echoing back to the client what it sent in
>   the draw parameter, in order to prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS)
>   attacks.

Comment: Dared to edit the answer :) Please mark your own answer as accepted. Have the feeling it will help people in the future.

Comment: Good and thanks for the help which led me to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

```
    function show(){
        $("#example").DataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            processing: true,       
            columns : [
                { data : 'FirstName' },
                { data : 'LastName' }
            ],    
            ajax: {
                url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/384sr",
                dataSrc : ''
           }
        });  
   }
   show();
```

**Html**

```
<table id="example" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jgt3mn8/110/)

Comment: I am talking about searching

Comment: Updated the question with server code, ajax request and response

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found your error, but check this out.

Verify the configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits@maxQueryString setting in the applicationhost.config or web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

```
//For me it was two things.

//wrap the table javascript with 

//function _displayItems(data) { var table = $('#...

//Then using the closing brackets:
//destroy then clear
    productsTable.destroy();
    productsTable.clear();
}

function _displayItems() {
  fetch(uri)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => _displayItems(data))
    .catch(error => console.error('Unable to get items.', error));
}

    var tableName = $('#data').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "data": data,
        "columns": [
            { "name": "name", "data": "name" },
            { "name": "id", "data": "id" },
            {
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    var buttonID = "edit_" + full.id;
                    return '<a id="' + buttonID + '" class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect editBtn" role="button">Edit</a>';
                }
            },
            {
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    var buttonID = "delete_" + full.id;
                    return ' <a id="' + buttonID + '" onclick="deleteUserRoleModal()" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger waves-effect removeRole" role="button">Delete</a>';
                }
            }
        ],
        "responsive": true,
        "dom": 'Bfrtip',
        "buttons": [
            'copy', 'excel', 'pdf',
            {
                text: 'Delete',
            }
        ],
        "initComplete": function () {
            this.api().columns([0]).every(function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select class="selectpicker" data-size="5" data-live-search="true"><option value="">Application Role (All)</option></select>')
                    .appendTo("#table").end()
                    .on('change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                            .draw();
                    });

                column.cells('', column[0]).render('display').sort().unique().each(function (d, j) {
                    if (column.search() === '^' + d + '$') {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '" selected="selected">' + d + '</option>')
                    }
                    else {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                    }
                });
            });
        },

        "bJqueryUI": true,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']],
        "aoPreSearchCols": [[1]],

        "lengthMenu": [
            [12, 24, 48, 1000],
            ['12', '24', '48', 'all']
        ],
        "language": {
            searchPlaceholder: " Role Screen ",
            search: " ",
        }
    });

    $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(productsTable, {
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
        ]
    });
    productsTable.buttons().container()
        .appendTo($('.col-sm-6:eq(0)', productsTable.table().container()));
    $("#todos" + "#table").DataTable({
        responsive: true
    });

    //destroy then clear
    productsTable.destroy();
    productsTable.clear();
}
```